# Secret sharing over reals - Difficulty with Computer implementation

Tags: secret-sharing

I asked a [question recently](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63427/secret-sharing-over-reals-constructing-a-k-n-threshold-scheme) regarding the paper ["Secret Sharing Over Infinite Domains" - B. Chor and E. Kushilevitz](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/0-387-34805-0_27.pdf) which describes a secret sharing scheme for real numbers in the interval $[0,1]$. I got a fantastic answer as to how to construct a $(k,n)$-scheme.

However, I am struggling to implement the [recommended scheme](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63430/62812) for a general case - I would like to believe there is an algorithm to do this; however, I was unable to do so. Below is a summary of where I am stuck -

For the case $(k,n) = (3,5)$, I used a "2-space diagonal assignment" technique which I have described below:

We have 10 independent $(3,3)$ schemes to construct denoted by
$$r_{j,1}, r_{j,2}, S - r_{j,1} - r_{j,2} \pmod 1 \;\;\forall j \in \{1,\ldots,10\}$$

let $r_{j,3}$ denotes $S - r_{j,1} - r_{j,2} \pmod 1$

My assignments were as follows;

$1 \rightarrow (r_{1,1},r_{2,2},r_{3,3},r_{6,1}, r_{7,2} ,r_{8,3} $)
$2 \rightarrow (r_{2,1},r_{3,2},r_{4,3},r_{7,1}, r_{8,2} ,r_{9,3} $)
$3 \rightarrow (r_{3,1},r_{4,2},r_{5,3},r_{8,1}, r_{9,2} ,r_{10,3}$)
$4 \rightarrow (r_{4,1},r_{5,2},r_{6,3},r_{9,1}, r_{10,2},r_{1,3} $)
$5 \rightarrow (r_{5,1},r_{6,2},r_{7,3},r_{10,1},r_{1,2} ,r_{2,3} $)

**I hypothesized that this assignment technique which appears correct is either re-usable for other (k,n) schemes or depends on the difference (n-k).**

I tried the both a 2 and 3- space diagonal assignment for a $(3,6)$ scheme..

However, **I was unable to work out an assignment technique for the said (and general) case.**

Would appreciate any help in finding a general assignment to progress further with my investigation into this scheme. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the definition of a $(k,n)$-threshold secret sharing scheme is that any group of at least $k$ players (out of $n$ total players) can recover the secret given their shares.  The naive method for constructing a threshold scheme out of a non-threshold scheme (which was recommended in your previous question's answer) is giving every possible $k$-combination of the $n$ players a fresh $(k,k)$ sharing of the secret.  (I'll note that this is only practical for small values of $n$.)

It seems that you are stuck on the question of how to enumerate all of the possible combinations.  A good reference is [this comprehensive answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14821001/1390231), which mentions several algorithms.

Here is a quick Python script that will calculate all of the combinations for $k=3, n=5$:

```
import itertools

players = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
k = 3
for subset in itertools.combinations(players, k):
    print(subset)
```

With the resultant subsets:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 2, 5)
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 5)
(1, 4, 5)
(2, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 5)
(2, 4, 5)
(3, 4, 5)
```

This is of course a general algorithm that will work for any values of $k$ and any set of players.

Comment: Just to make it clear for anyone who might stumble across this thread, this naive method is _not_ a practical way to construct a $k$-out-of-$n$ threshold secret sharing scheme. Sure, it works, but the shares will be _huge_. Even for your example of $k=3$, $n=5$, you'll end up with shares that are about 10 times as big as for an equivalent instance of e.g. Shamir's scheme.